# Why codeigniter2 doesn't store the csrf_hash in a more secure way, such as session?

Tags: php, security, codeigniter, csrf, codeigniter-2

Why generated CSRF protection token is not saved and used via SESSION like suggested [here](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2008/10/16/how-to-csrf-protect-all-your-forms/)? Currently in CI2, the CSRF protection mechanism (in Security class) is such:

1.generate a unique value for CSRF token in _csrf_set_hash() function:

```
$this->csrf_hash = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
```

2.Insert that token into form hidden field (using form_open helper)

3.A user submits the form and a server gets the token via POST. The CI performs token verification in "_sanitize_globals()" function in Input class:

```
$this->security->csrf_verify();
```

4.The function "csrf_verify" of Security class just checks is POST['token'] set and is POST['token'] equal to COOKIE['token'];

```
public function csrf_verify(){

// If no POST data exists we will set the CSRF cookie
if (count($_POST) == 0)
{
    return $this->csrf_set_cookie();
}

// Do the tokens exist in both the _POST and _COOKIE arrays?
if ( ! isset($_POST[$this->_csrf_token_name]) OR
         ! isset($_COOKIE[$this->_csrf_cookie_name]))
{
    $this->csrf_show_error();
}

// Do the tokens match?

if ($_POST[$this->_csrf_token_name] != $_COOKIE[$this->_csrf_cookie_name])
{
    $this->csrf_show_error();
}

// We kill this since we're done and we don't want to
// polute the _POST array
unset($_POST[$this->_csrf_token_name]);

// Nothing should last forever
unset($_COOKIE[$this->_csrf_cookie_name]);
$this->_csrf_set_hash();
$this->csrf_set_cookie();

log_message('debug', "CSRF token verified ");

return $this;
}
```

Why not to store token in session? IMHO just checking is POST['token'] non-empty and is equal to COOKIE['token'] is not sufficient because both might be sent by an evil site.

Comment: I don't think an evil site could set a cookie value for the 'good' site: neither can read nor write cookies for the other domain. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe you are right, maybe it's just another approach to SESSION use. Just curious is it the same safety.

Comment: I made revision to my question, please check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CodeIgniter, they don't use native PHP sessions anywhere in the code.

The example you provided is shown using native PHP sessions.

While using CodeIgniter Session class, there's either: store data via cookies, or store them in database. [ reference: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html ]

While checking for csrf data, it wouldn't make sense to check the database every time, it would be plausible to store them in the cookies.

I think it's generally safe, but there are some windows of vulnerability with this method. Perhaps encrypting it with server side key might help increase the security...

**EDIT:**

https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/CsrfProtection#Sessionindependentnonce

According to the article, it says that CSRF Protection with Session independent nonce (used by CodeIgniter) has a vulnerability to CSRF + MITM Attack ([Man-in-the-Middle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)):

> The attacker can set the CSRF cookie using Set-Cookie, and then supply
>   a matching token in the POST form data. Since the site does not tie
>   the session cookies to the CSRF cookies, it has no way of determining
>   that the CSRF token + cookie are genuine (doing hashing etc. of one of
>   them will not work, as the attacker can just get a valid pair from the
>   site directly, and use that pair in the attack).

Pretty much, the function **csrf_verify()** only checks whether the cookie and input POST is 
equal, which both can be created through simple javascript. You should think twice about using this if you are serious about security.

Source: [How does this Man-In-The-Middle attack work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066462/how-does-this-man-in-the-middle-attack-work)

Comment: Actually, I was thinking the same as you :) And the question was, can  an evil site (www.badsite.com) set a cookie for good site (www.goodsite.com), so that the token in the cookie would match the token in POST sent by evil site, and so the good site would receive the POST and cookie set by an evil site? Somehow from the answers, I thought you cannon set a cookie to other domain (from evilsite) and expect it would be sent to good site by browser automatically.

Comment: And even YES, if an evil site has some javascript code that a victim download from an evil site then the javascript code IMHO might alter related cookies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402348/getting-setting-cookies-on-different-domains-with-javascript-or-other

Comment: Correct, no third party sites can manually alter cookies, but cookies can be altered through malicious javascript.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few reasons.

First being that storing the token in the cookie is not insecure.  Anti-CSRF is not designed to prevent automated posting of content, it is to prevent forging a request as an authenticated user (via an iframe, or a simple link).  So long as the token itself is not guessable, that is enough.

The second being if it's stored in the session, then you need sessions enabled, this also causes usability issues because if your session times out and you have a page open with a form, you can no longer submit that form (even if the form itself doesn't require a logged in state).

Comment: I don't quite agree, it's checking cookies and input post, which is quite redundant to do so, since both can be altered in a way. Basically, just have to set the cookie and input the same, something that can easily be done with little bit of javascript. I believe this is a security hole in CodeIgniter. Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066462/how-does-this-man-in-the-middle-attack-work

Comment: Matthew: please, take a look at my comment below too. It would be interesting to know, is it sufficient to use such approach.

Comment: This may be beyond my scope of understanding, but if the cookie is set to secure only, then it should not be susceptible to this particular type of attack.

Answer (score 1):

Because CSRF stands for "Cross-site Request Forgery."  An example of this attack would be if you knew someone had a wordpress install at `http://somedomain.com/wordpress`.  You could get them to click on a new link, which would really go do something bad over on their wordpress control panel.  CSRF was designed to prevent this, verifying that the action taken was intended by the user taking the action.

Even if someone knew how to forge both the cookie and the hidden form field to match, there's no way to do that cross-site, and there's no forgery to prevent anyway.

Comment: please take a look at @tpae answer and comments below.

Comment: What do you want me to see?  CSRF isn't a replacement for authentication, but it--coupled with good authentication--prevents unintended actions from an already authenticated user...